# WCF Authentication CookieContainer empty - Universal Windows App

Tags: wcf, cookies, portable-class-library, windows-10-universal, cookiecontainer

I'm logging into a WCF authentication service on a universal windows app, when I try to access the CookieContainer it is empty.

The same code on a Windows 8.1 app works fine.

I have AllowCookies set to true for the basicbindings. The services are located in a PCL which allows me to use the CookieContainer property which isn't available when I use 'Add Service Reference' on the universal windows app directly.

(UWP App) MainPage

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
binding.AllowCookies = true;

new ClassLibrary1.Class1().Login(binding);
```

(PCL) Class1

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Login(BasicHttpBinding binding)
    {
        var Client = new ServiceReference1.AuthenticationServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("*****.svc"));

        Client.LoginAsync("*****", "*****", null, false);

        Client.LoginCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Result)
            {
                CookieContainer CookieContainer = Client.CookieContainer;
                CookieCollection Cookies = CookieContainer.GetCookies(Client.Endpoint.Address.Uri);

                Cookie Cookie = Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"];
            }
        };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please upload the code?

Comment: Did you  configure the ASP.NET authentication service on a Web server to make it available to clients as a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service? Did you add a web service reference to your client? From your code, it seems you add a service reference client, but this client doesn't contain CookieContainer property.

Comment: I have used 'Add Service Reference' on the PCL project so the CookieContainer does exist in this instance but the container has zero contents on successful authentication. It may relate to this known issue but I'm not sure https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/908